# Not able to View Calendar

Tags: android, calendar, samsung-mobile

In my application, I want to open device default calendar using code/programatically. I am using this code :

```
private void viewAllCalender() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent i = new Intent();
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 8 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 14){
            i.setClassName("com.android.calendar","com.android.calendar.LaunchActivity");
        }else if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 15){    
            i.setClassName("com.google.android.calendar", "com.android.calendar.LaunchActivity");
        }else{
            i.setClassName("com.android.calendar","com.android.calendar.LaunchActivity");
        }
        startActivity(i);
    }
```

**IT IS WORKING FOR ALL THE DEVICES BUT IT IS NOT WORKING IN SAMSUNG S3 - (BUILD SDK VERSION - 17)**

Please help me to figure out what the problem is??

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You gotta realise that you can't expect an Android device to have a certain application. Not even the play app can be expected to be installed. The correct way of doing this is simply not using .setClassName and then let the user decide what to do.

There is a dozen different calendar apps and the phone manufactures each have their own...

**Edit**

If you want to add an event to calendar you could use my CalendarOrganizer which handles a lot of these issues:

```
public class CalendarOrganizer {
    private final static int ICE_CREAM_BUILD_ID = 14;
    /**
     * Creates a calendar intent going from startTime to endTime
     * @param startTime
     * @param endTime
     * @param context
     * @return true if the intent can be handled and was started, 
     * false if the intent can't be handled
     */
    public static boolean createEvent(long startTime, long endTime, String title, String description, 
            String location, boolean isAllDay, Context context) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
        int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        if(sdk < ICE_CREAM_BUILD_ID) {
            // all SDK below ice cream sandwich
            intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
            intent.putExtra("beginTime", startTime);
            intent.putExtra("endTime", endTime);
            intent.putExtra("title", title);
            intent.putExtra("description", description);
            intent.putExtra("eventLocation", location);
            intent.putExtra("allDay", isAllDay);

//          intent.putExtra("rrule", "FREQ=YEARLY");
        } else {
            // ice cream sandwich and above
            intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
            intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, startTime);
            intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, endTime);
            intent.putExtra(Events.TITLE, title);
            intent.putExtra(Events.ACCESS_LEVEL, Events.ACCESS_PRIVATE);
            intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_ALL_DAY , isAllDay);
            intent.putExtra(Events.DESCRIPTION, description);
            intent.putExtra(Events.EVENT_LOCATION, location);

//          intent.putExtra(Events.RRULE, "FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=10") 
        }
        try {
            context.startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you please elaborate how can I solve this problem in Samsung S3 ?

Comment: @BorntoWin I've added an example showing how to add an event to calendar, but it's not clear from your post if this is what you are looking for. If you want the open the calendar app then you are in no luck. You can do like me and put a try catch block around it an notify the user whenever the app isn't on the phone...

Answer (score 0):

To open the calendar application refer to the intent-view guide http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html#intent-view